# How to bind a self referencing object to a datagrid - Ex: ObjectA[n] is a prop of ObjectA[m] in same row, selectable in a ComboBox of another column

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

While operating on a `DataGrid` I am receiving this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: ''DeferRefresh' is not allowed
> during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.'

How does one resolve this?

**Code**

I have two lists of objects "**Feeders**" and "**Eaters**". Each object has a property called `FedFrom`, which points to a `Feeder` object by `Tag`. The way my data is setup is actually using "Tags" I store the `Tag` in the "**FedFrom**" property as a string instead of the entire "Feeder" object. Also, FedFrom can be blank

**Feeders**

| Feeder Tag (textbox) | FedFrom (FeederTag) (combobox) |
| --- | --- |
| fTagA | 'blank' |
| fTagB | fTagA |
| fTagC | fTagB |
| fTagD | fTagC |

**Eaters**

| Eater Tag (textbox) | FedFrom (FeederTag) (combobox) |
| --- | --- |
| eTagA | fTagD |
| eTagB | fTagC |
| eTagC | fTagC |
| eTagD | fTagB |

I display two `DataGrids` one for **Feeders** and one for **eaters**. The **FedFrom** column on both grids is a combobox column that lists all the available **Feeders** in the `ObservableCollection`. When I add new **feeders** everything updates correctly. In the eaters datagrid, the FedFrom column combobox sees the newly added Feeders and I assume it also works in the feeders grid as well, but I get the following error as soon as I click on the FedFrom combobox in the **Feeders** datagrid:

System.InvalidOperationException: ''DeferRefresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction.'

I think this makes sense as I'm self referencing the collection, so my question is how do I get around this? I'm just using basic WPF binding. The ItemsSource for each combobox is the **Feeders** collection with DisplayMemberPath = "Tag".

This done in the code behind so that I can control how columns are autogenerated. Not sure if this is an issue.

```
ObservableCollection<Feeder> Feeders = new ObservableCollection<Feeder>();
ObservableCollection<Eater> Eaters = new ObservableCollection<Eater>();

public class Feeder
{
   Tag {get; set;}
   FedFrom {get; set;}  //this is where I want to store feeder tag
}

public class Eater
{
   Tag {get; set;}
   FedFrom {get; set;}  //this is where I want to store feeder tag
}

private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "FedFrom") 
    {
        var cb = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
        cb.ItemsSource = DteqList;
        cb.SelectedValuePath = "Tag";
        cb.DisplayMemberPath = "Tag";
        cb.SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("FedFrom"); //allows binding to the property

        cb.CellStyle  = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
        cb.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent));
        cb.CellStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black));
        cb.Header = ((PropertyDescriptor)e.PropertyDescriptor).DisplayName;
        e.Column = cb;
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer posted here was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461714/wpf-datagrid-combobox-causes-invalidoperationexception

Comment: Find the exact answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461714/wpf-datagrid-combobox-causes-invalidoperationexception

Comment: I'll go ahead and make this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461714/wpf-datagrid-combobox-causes-invalidoperationexception then.  Thanks for letting us know the resolution!